# Magento Find Checkout Method

Tags: magento

How to find [checkout](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Quote.html#getCheckoutMethod) method is whether "guest" or "register".

`getCheckoutMethod` is deprecated.So is it advisable to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and where it is deprecated?  latest magento 1.7.0.2 seems to use it and define it and not mention anything about deprecation of this method

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getCheckoutMethod();
```

this method is defined in multiple places

```
grep ' getCheckoutMethod' app/code -rsn
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php:165:    public function getCheckoutMethod()
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php:661:    public function getCheckoutMethod()
```

Comment: [Docs](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Quote.html#getCheckoutMethod) shows `getCheckoutMethod()` deprecated after magento1.4beta1.

Comment: so ask it from the place where it is not deprecated.

Comment: The weird thing is that the checkout itself uses the depreciated method in the class Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php (at least in Magento EE 1.13.1 ...).

Answer (score 1):

getCheckoutMethod is deprecated via the quote model, so via the checkout_onepage model is not deprecated.

```
/**
 * Return quote checkout method code
 *
 * @deprecated after 1.4 beta1 it is checkout module responsibility
 * @param boolean $originalMethod if true return defined method from begining
 * @return string
 */
public function getCheckoutMethod($originalMethod = false)
{
    if ($this->getCustomerId() && !$originalMethod) {
        return self::CHECKOUT_METHOD_LOGIN_IN;
    }
    return $this->_getData('checkout_method');
}
```